# Using PL/SQL, select specific key-value from the JSON response after consuming the REST API

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql

Below is the PLSQL code i am using to get response after hitting the API,

```
set serveroutput on;
set define off;
declare
l_req utl_http.req;
l_resp utl_http.resp;
buffer varchar2(32000);
response JSON_OBJECT_T;
response_list   json_key_list;
result_obj JSON_OBJECT_T;
v_url varchar2(32000);
v_par varchar2(32000);
payload varchar2(32000);
p_web_user  varchar2(320) := 'idev';
p_web_pwd  varchar2(320) := 'abcd2';
plan_id number;
exec_id number;
p_status_code  number;
p_err_msg  varchar2(32000);
response_txt varchar2(32000);
v_start_cnt NUMBER:=0;
v_end_cnt NUMBER:=0;
v_execution_id VARCHAR2(200);

begin
    v_url := 'http://someapi.dev.com/1234/run/';
    dbms_output.put_line(v_url);
    l_req := utl_http.begin_request(
                                    url => v_url,
                                    method => 'GET'
                                    );
    utl_http.set_authentication (l_req, p_web_user, p_web_pwd);    
    l_resp := utl_http.get_response(r => l_req);    
            utl_http.read_text(l_resp,buffer);
            dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
            utl_http.end_response(l_resp);
    if l_resp.status_code = 200 then
        response := JSON_OBJECT_T.parse(buffer);
        dbms_output.put_line('140');
        response_list := response.get_keys;
        
        FOR counter IN 1 .. response_list.COUNT 
        LOOP 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 
            response_list (counter) 
         || ' = ' 
         || response.get_string (response_list (counter))); 
        END LOOP;      
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('In ELse module');
        dbms_output.put_line(l_resp.status_code);
        dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
    end if;
    exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('Error : '|| sqlerrm);
end;
```

And this is the response I am getting, this is the whole of response that I am receiving but I need only 2 or 3 Keys with values,

```
{
  "GetSupplyPlanRunRespABM" : {
    "ResponseHeader" : {
      "TransactionID" : "",
      "Timestamp" : "2021-03-12T18:07:51.973Z",
      "Status" : "SUCCESS"
    },
    "GetSupplyPlanRunResp" : {
      "EndDate" : "2021-03-10T09:03:38.629+00:00",
      "ExecutionId" : "67890",
      "ExecutionUser" : "idev",
      "JobId" : "200170",
      "PlanId" : "12345",
      "StartDate" : "2021-03-10T08:53:48.168+00:00",
      "Status" : "2",
      "links" : [ {
        "rel" : "self",
        "href" : "http://someapi.dev.com/1234/run/",
        "name" : "Runs",
        "kind" : "item"
      }, {
        "rel" : "canonical",
        "href" : "http://someapi.dev.com/1234/run/",
        "name" : "Runs",
        "kind" : "item"
      }, {
        "rel" : "parent",
        "href" : "http://someapi.dev.com/1234/run/",
        "name" : "Runs",
        "kind" : "item"
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

I just want to get only 2 key values as decribed below,

"StartDate" : "2021-03-10T08:53:48.168+00:00",
"Status" : "2"

I am not able to do that, as only fix I am getting is using to_string and substr method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate down the JSON structure in the [JSON_OBJECT_T](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/json-types.html#GUID-BDE10AAA-445B-47B5-8A39-D86C8EA99283) response, and either get strings:

```
response
    .get_Object('GetSupplyPlanRunRespABM')
    .get_Object('GetSupplyPlanRunResp')
    .get_String('StartDate')

response
    .get_Object('GetSupplyPlanRunRespABM')
    .get_Object('GetSupplyPlanRunResp')
    .get_String('Status')
```

or as specific data types:

```
response
    .get_Object('GetSupplyPlanRunRespABM')
    .get_Object('GetSupplyPlanRunResp')
    .get_Timestamp('StartDate')

response
    .get_Object('GetSupplyPlanRunRespABM')
    .get_Object('GetSupplyPlanRunResp')
    .get_Number('Status')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c024aa676722c359b73d98be255deb56) supplying the buffer as a fixed value; which shows output as:

```
StartDate (string): 2021-03-10T08:53:48.168+00:00
Status (string): 2
StartDate (timestamp): 10-MAR-21 08.53.48.168000
Status (number): 2
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution is working as expected, I am able to get the desired keys only !! Actually I was doing the same in wrong place apparently, I was using get_object with l_resp(l_resp := utl_http.get_response(r => l_req)).